# Проблема с биндингом ObservableCollection к ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, observablecollection

Доброе время суток. Прошу помочь найти, или указать в чём ошибка в следующей ситуации...

Есть класс Session:

```
public class Session : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _dirPath;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public string DirPath
    {
        get => _dirPath;
        set
        {
            if (_dirPath == value) return;
            _dirPath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Есть коллекция, объявленная во ViewModel'e (MainViewModel):

```
private ObservableCollection<Session> _sessionsList;

    public ObservableCollection<Session> SessionsList
    {
        get => _sessionsList ?? (_sessionsList = new ObservableCollection<Session>());
        set => _sessionsList = value;
    }
```

Коллекция SessionsList привязана ItemsControl'у следующим образом (MainViewModel не DataContext данной View):

```xaml
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3" Height="340"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              Margin="0,12,0,0">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SessionsList}"
                  DataContext="{x:Static classes:Core.MainViewModel}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <extentions:LastSessionItem DirPath="{Binding Path=DirPath}" />
               </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Где LastSessionItem - это CustomControl, реализующий в то числе:

```
    public string DirPath
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(PropertyDirPath);
        set => SetValue(PropertyDirPath, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyDirPath = DependencyProperty.Register("DirPath",
        typeof(string), typeof(LastSessionItem), new PropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // не срабатывает...нет изменений
    }
```

SessionsList заполняется при создании класса MainViewModel.
Вроде, всё верно. Однако...DirPath не биндится, остаётся равным null. Ошибок студия тоже никаких не показывает

Comment: В окно Output какие-нибудь ошибки байндинга выводятся?

Comment: Нет, всё чисто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как же важно иногда в слух сформулировать вопрос (или просто написать)...
Проблему решил. В классе LastSessionItem было ошибочно сделано следующие:

```
public LastSessionItem()
{
    //...    
}
```